# Liquibase schema : how to do preconditions check for Drop Index before create index

Tags: schema, liquibase

I am attempting to address the following puzzle concerning a Liquibase schema XML script. My goal is to create a new index for a PostgreSQL table using Liquibase schema, with the following conditions

1. If the index already exists, the script should drop the existing index and then create a new one.
2. If the index does not exist, the script should skip the drop index condition and proceed to create the new index.
3. Importantly, the script should not halt the Liquibase schema executions. Even if the specified conditions fail, the script should continue to run the subsequent tasks.

below script executed
e.g.

```xml
<databaseChangeLog   ..........">

    <changeSet author="ABC" id="11111111">
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <tableExists tableName="XYZ"/>
            <columnExists tableName="XYZ"
                columnName="point" />
                <!-- Check if the index exists -->
                <not>
                <indexExists indexName="idx_XYZ"/>
                <not>
        </preConditions>
        <!-- Drop the index if it exists -->
           <dropIndex tableName="XYZ" indexName="idx_XYZ" />
         <!-- Create the new index -->
        <createIndex indexName="idx_XYZ"
            tableName="XYZ" unique="false">
            <column name="point" />
        </createIndex>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Error:

```
-E- [liquischema] An Error occured in Liquibase:  
-E- [liquischema] liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: 
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: 
Migration failed for changeset schema/migrations/0021_CreateIndex.xml::11111111::ABC:
     
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: index "idx_XYZ" does not exist 
[Failed SQL: (0) DROP INDEX public.idx_XYZ] I- [liquischema] Finished. 
Closing connection...
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right, that logic could be implemented by making two separate changesets:

> If the index already exists, the script should drop the existing index
> and then create a new one.

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <indexExists indexName="idx_XYZ"/>
    </preConditions>
    <dropIndex tableName="XYZ" indexName="idx_XYZ"/>
    <createIndex indexName="idx_XYZ" tableName="XYZ" unique="false">
        <column name="point"/>
    </createIndex> 
</changeSet>
```

> If the index does not exist, the script should skip the drop index
> condition and proceed to create the new index.

```
<changeSet id="foo1" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <indexExists indexName="idx_XYZ"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createIndex indexName="idx_XYZ" tableName="XYZ" unique="false">
        <column name="point"/>
    </createIndex> 
</changeSet>
```

> Importantly, the script should not halt the Liquibase schema
> executions. Even if the specified conditions fail, the script should
> continue to run the subsequent tasks.

due to `onFail="MARK_RAN"` the execution will not be halted.

**If index exists in the first place**:

- the first changeSet will be executed and the second one will be skipped

**If index doesn't exist in the first place**:

- the first changeSet will be skipped and the second one will be executed